# Problem in django login with correct password and phone number

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to log in with phone and password, but I can't, and I get this error: `invalid phone number data` and in admin panel
password = Invalid password or unknown encryption algorithm.
What do I do?
I customized User model and I added otp option to register by ghasedakpack.
I also set backend authentication in setting:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'account.authentication.EmailAuthenticationBackend',
    'account.authentication.PhoneAuthenticationBackend',
]
```

view:

```py
class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):enter code here
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home:home')
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
    
    def post(self, request):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['phone'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home:home')
            else:
                form.add_error('phone', 'invalid phone number data')
        else:
            form.add_error('phone', 'invalid data')"
        return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

model :

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="آدرس ایمیل",
        max_length=257,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="نام کامل")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, verbose_name="تلفن")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='گذر واژه')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "کاربر"
        verbose_name_plural = "کاربران"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin


class Otp(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, verbose_name='شماره تماس')
    token = models.CharField(max_length=111, null=True)
    code = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='کد')
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "اعتبار سنجی"
        verbose_name_plural = "اعتبار سنجی ها"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone
```

register and otp view:

```py
SMS = ghasedakpack.Ghasedak("????????????????????????????")


class RegisterView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home:home')
        form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        user = None
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            rand_code = randint(1000, 9999)
            SMS.verification(
                {'receptor': cd["phone"], 'type': '1', 'template': 'shop', 'param1': rand_code})
            token = str(uuid4())
            Otp.objects.create(phone=cd['phone'], code=rand_code, token=token)
            print(rand_code)
            user = User.objects.create(
                phone=cd['phone'],
                fullname=cd['fullname'],
                email=cd['email'],
                password=cd['password'],
            )
            return redirect(reverse('account:otp') + f'?token={token}')
        else:
            form.add_error('phone', 'invalid data')

        return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'form': form, 'user': user})


class OtpView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = OtpForm()
        return render(request, 'account/otp.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        form = OtpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            if Otp.objects.filter(code=cd['code'], token=token).exists():
                otp = Otp.objects.get(token=token)
                user, is_created = User.objects.get_or_create(phone=otp.phone)
                login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                otp.delete()
                return redirect('home:home')
        else:
            form.add_error('phone', 'invalid data')

        return render(request, 'account/otp.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: did you define a custom use model? Did you create a custom register view?

Comment: yes i created my custom user

Comment: Can you share the model, manager and the view where you *register* users?

Comment: ok , where I can share those?

Comment: I edited code and added related parts